# How can I add/remove class using $this

Tags: html, jquery, css

**Please see code below**

```js
$(".nwe-cl-icontext").click(function () {
  $(this).parent().toggleClass("nwe-active");
 //  $(this).removeClass("nwe-active");
})
```

```css
.nwe-cl-c.nwe-active {
background: red;
}

.nwe-cl-c {
background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nwe-g-m">
    <div class="nwe-cl-c nwe-active">
        <div class="nwe-cl-icon-m is"></div>
        <div class="nwe-cl-icontext">btn3</div>
    </div>

    <div class="nwe-cl-c">
        <div class="nwe-cl-icon-m is"></div>
        <div class="nwe-cl-icontext">btn2</div>
    </div>

    <div class="nwe-cl-c">
        <div class="nwe-cl-icon-m is"></div>
        <div class="nwe-cl-icontext">btn3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can anyone help me with how can I accomplish this? Currently, by using `toggleClass` I can add/remove classes. But my goal is when I click the second button the `nwe-class` should add to the second parent same with the 3rd and so on the parent.

Comment: What are you seeing that should happen that is not? When I click on one of the three green divs it turns red, and when I click on a red one it turns green. You talk about adding the `nwe-class` but there is no class of that name.

Comment: hi Heretic sorry, false information, I mean nwe-active

Comment: I'm referring the class of `nwe-active`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So select the element with the class, make sure it is not the one you clicked on, and remove the class.

```js
$(".nwe-cl-icontext").click(function() {
  const elem = $(this).parent();
  elem.toggleClass("nwe-active");
  $('.nwe-active').not(elem).removeClass("nwe-active");
})
```

```css
.nwe-cl-c.nwe-active {
  background: red;
}

.nwe-cl-c {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nwe-g-m">
  <div class="nwe-cl-c nwe-active">
    <div class="nwe-cl-icon-m is"></div>
    <div class="nwe-cl-icontext">btn3</div>
  </div>

  <div class="nwe-cl-c">
    <div class="nwe-cl-icon-m is"></div>
    <div class="nwe-cl-icontext">btn2</div>
  </div>

  <div class="nwe-cl-c">
    <div class="nwe-cl-icon-m is"></div>
    <div class="nwe-cl-icontext">btn3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```